# Javascript files being truncated

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET Development Server and EPiServer CMS, FF3 and IE7

Edited Question - Removed irelevant distractions as I now realise it has nothing to do with dynamic content.

Every so often javascript files I am working on are not getting fully downloaded. The file I am currently having a problem with is only 49 lines long and is getting cut off with only 30 or characters to go.

Anyone else seen this?

TIA

Pat

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your web server. How are you running / debugging the web site?

Comment: I MUST clarify The dynamic-ness and the placement of the files in the page is unsuprisiongly irrelevant. I have just requested the file directly and it is truncated.

The web server is ASP.NET Development Server with the EPiServer CMS.

I am going to take a closer look at EPiServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a caching bug with StaticFileHandler. Check out [this blog post](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Per/Archive/2009/3/Files-being-cached-too-aggressively-in-R2/) and [this thread on Episerver World](http://world.episerver.com/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=28423&epslanguage=en).

Haven't tried it fully yet, but they say setting cacheControl="private" on staticFile should solve the problem "sort of".

```
<staticFile  expirationTime="1.0:0:0" cacheControl="private" />
```

Comment: This solution seems to solve the problem for me, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot, but try switching to the ASP.NET StaticFileHandler in web.config.